# Error while starting hello-world-server.js in Enide Studio, CreateFileandSetSecurity failed with FALSE (Expected on FAT Partitions) GLE: 3

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

I am trying to run hello-world-server.js from Enide Studio 0.5.33 (X32) and getting the following error , whereas i m able to run it from command prompt

```
node hello-world-server.js
```

> CreateFileandSetSecurity failed with FALSE (Expected on FAT
>   Partitions) GLE: 3 CreateFileandSetSecurity failed with TRUE (not
>   expected) GLE: 3

Comment: After some search found the following link which seems to have removed the above mentioned errors, but my node is still not working due to some other reason. http://readlist.com/lists/cygwin.com/cygwin/0/1465.html

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you updated Nodeclipse plugin to 0.10 (as of Feb 2014).
Then in Preferences -> Nodeclipse you will see Java version that is currently used

Java 7 x32 is recommended for Windows.
Some related issues are reference on http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ and in built-in Help and online Help.

Specifically for your case you should [create an issue](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues) and give info mentioned at http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support

> Should you report a bug, please include the following:
>
> 1. Nodeclipse version number (like 0.4 or 0.8)
> 2. Eclipse version number (like 4.3.1 Kepler or 4.4.0)
> 3. Eclipse distribution (e.g. Eclipse for Java EE  Developers)
> 4. A detailed description of the steps necessary to reproduce the problem.
> 5. Screenshot and stack trace, that you can get from Eclipse Error Log View (Window -> Show View ...) or from '.log' file from the directory '.metadata' in your workspace.
>    See example issue #78